# Fonts that combine special characters as ligature

Tags: ligatures

In german, there are three special characters ä,ö and ü that are often written as two: ae,oe,ue.

Is there a font, that shows an "ä" whenever the letters "ae" appear?

I thought this would be solveable with a pseudo ligature, that combines both letters.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This must be language dependent then, mustn't it?  `hue` in English should'nt be transformed into `hü`, most likely

Comment: Never heard of one. And I can tell you some points why you won't find one, I fear: Aerobic, Oeuvre, Aerodynamik,... zueinander, soeben,... Soest, Coesfeld,... Rafael, Samuel, Noemi, Joel, Nathanael, Ismael ... Fuest...

Comment: Yesterday evening I had to smile when thinking about you having typeset Manuel Neuer's soccer shirt.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, there isn't.

In addition, this "feature" would cause more trouble than gain, because there are lots of words in German where the ligature is not wanted, e.g., *aktuell*, *Bauer*, *neue*, *raue*, *Osloer*, *Bebraer*, ...

If you really want to create such kind of font, you are free to do so: Copy a given font to a new name, convert the tfm (TeX Font metrics) file with the utility `tftopl` into a property list, and than add ligatures by editing the property list. The relevant section of the property list reads (here taken from the font ecrm1000 for the letter f):

```
(LIGTABLE
   (LABEL C f)
   (LIG C i O 34)
   (LIG C f O 33)
   (LIG C l O 35)
```

so you can easily add ligatures to the **renamed** font like

```
   (LABEL C a)
   (LIG C e O 304)
```

and convert it back to a valid tfm file by using `tftopl`. (In fact, you will probably find the `(LABEL C a)` statement initiating the section of kernings after the letter *a* in the tfm file.

Please note, that renaming the fonts is necessary for two reasons:

1. Avoid confusion between the originals and the changed fonts
2. It is required by the licences of typical fonts coming with a TeX distribution (e.g., the Computer Modern fonts or the ec fonts).

Comment: Could you use such a font in other programs? for ex. create a webfont for use on a website?

Comment: @rubo77 Probably not, I am not aware of large scale adoption of TeX fonts by communities outside TeX (The only exception I know is the programm `groff` which can produce `dvi` files directly from *roff input)

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the "ae", "oe", and "ue" strings globally during input processing, by using LuaLaTeX. However, I wouldn't advise anyone actually do so. The following sample sentence illustrates why it wouldn't be a good idea.

[image]

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,luacode,luatexbase} 

\begin{luacode}
function double_vowel_to_umlaut ( x )
      x =  string.gsub ( x, "ae", "ä") 
      x =  string.gsub ( x, "oe", "ö") 
      x =  string.gsub ( x, "ue", "ü") 
      return ( x )
end
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{%
   luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer", 
      double_vowel_to_umlaut, "doublevowel_to_umlaut")}}

\begin{document}
Samuel, Joel, und Rafael trafen sich beim Taekwondo zu neuen Duellen. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get this interesting error: “/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty:231: Undefined control sequence.  l.231   \pdftrü”

Comment: @Thérèse I guess that `\pdftrü` was `\pdftrue` before... Mico put the function in an `\AtBeginDocument` directive which is hopefully more stable and works for you.